# PayPal Recurring Plan List is NULL

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm attempting to get a list of all Recurring Payment plans using the C# API.  The result is always NULL.  What am I doing wrong?  I setup and tested other similar API requests such as Invoie.GetAll and that works, so I am confident my user account is setup correctly, I have a good auth token, etc.

Here is my code (note: I've tried passing the optional parameters too with no luck).  Perhaps there is a bug with the Api?

```
        var plans = PayPal.Api.Plan.List(_apiContext);
        return Xml(plans);
```

Comment: This issue raised here in GIT.  Still looking for a workaround though.  https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/issues/87

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to use Express Checkout of the [NVP and SOAP API Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/).  I have something working now.

Comment: Further clarification to the issue:  I am making another API call to Amazon Dynamo DB and it complains when the securityProtocol is Tls12.  Not sure this is the best solution, but I set the security protocol just before each Api call.  The only thing that I am not sure of is concurrency in a website.  Is this a static setting or thread safe?  If thread safe than no issue, otherwise I am going to run into all sort of more issues!